# Read .rdata without R

Tags: r, matlab, io, rdata

I have received an .rdata file with what I think should be a list of co-ordinates (x,y) and their corresponding gray value; however, I do not know exactly the data type/format within the .rdata file. Is there a way for me to read these data without R? I do not have access to R. I have Excel and Matlab on a Mac. Please help. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to pass on the data (my Googling tells me someone familiar with R can export the data into a text of csv file easily).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've just discovered I can download R. So I can try to export it myself if I could have some assistance-thank you.

Comment: Probably the best choice would be to load the data in R and save it in HDF5

Comment: Hi all, thanks. Sorry for the question. I've solved it now by downloading R, reading it in and exporting as a CSV file. No biggie!

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded R, read the `.rdata` in using `load()` and saved it out again using `write.csv()`.